# AngularJS tutorial - missing web-server.js file, attempting to follow instructions exactly

Tags: angularjs

I am attempting to follow the AngularJS tutorial.

The documentation specifically mentions using nodejs to start a basic server. See http://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/ step 5: "you can use node to run scripts\web-server.js, a simple bundled http server."

That's great, but web-server.js is not part of the angular-phonecat project. I followed the instructions exactly. The file is even missing from the from the master repo on github: https://github.com/angular/angular-phonecat/tree/master/scripts

So, could someone please either A) provide the web-server.js file, or B) tell me what I'm missing.

Thanks

Comment: Did you install `node`?

Comment: Yep, node is working fine.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this was an accident and someone deleted the web-server.js file from the repo. I recreated the web-server.js file from github history, saved it to a file in angular-phonecat/scripts, and now the node server runs fine. I'm leaving this open though, maybe the powers that be will see it and fix the repo issue.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand they use [http-server](https://www.npmjs.org/package/http-server) like dependency for npm.
So after

```
npm install http-server -g
```

you can simply run

```
node http-server
```

**UPD:**
found even more simple way - run in project dir:

```
npm start
```

Comment: Thanks - This did not work from me (cannot find module 'http-server', cannot find module 'start') but it makes sense. I expect something like this is the right answer if they intentionally removed the web-server.js file but just haven't updated the docs yet.

Comment: just check that you are inside project folder and you have package.json there

Answer (score 1):

Same thing for me! There was a revision that deleted this file, so I checkout out the earlier revision and have copied the web-server.js from it: 7b1d98830f5f7780108da3755b84c2713be3eb44

Answer (score 0):

The answer is simple - the tutorial is changing and web-server.js is no longer needed. However, I started the tutorial before it was updated to reflect the change.

Thanks everyone for looking into this.

Comment: Hi ! I m start with pluralsight video ! and there is no web-server.js !!! is there any new tutorial for new version of angular-seed ??

Answer (score 0):

Run the Command `ng add @nguniversal/express-engine` this will create `server.ts` file.

Answer (score -1):

Try to execute the `node scripts/web-server.js` with administrator access. (command)

Comment: I don't have admin access (ugh), but that wouldn't help - the file web-server.js is not present on my file system. I think I found the commit on github that removed it - maybe - I don't usually browse commit history (https://github.com/angular/angular-phonecat/commit/c4bd23b1ed217750ea0e36455441b729418fab03)

Comment: Try to build your own server using node.js `http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/node-js-server-side-javascript/`